# Double-ended Priority Queue using a doubly LinkedList

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, comparator, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement a Double-ended Priority Queue using a doubly LinkedList

```
public class ListDoubleEndedPriorityQueue<AnyType> implements DoubleEndedPriorityQueue<AnyType>{

private Comparator<? super AnyType> cmp;
private Node<AnyType> first = null;
private Node<AnyType> last  = null;
private int size = 0;
```

this is my node class

```
private static class Node<AnyType>{

    private Node<AnyType> next;
    private Node<AnyType> prev;
    private AnyType e;

    public Node(AnyType data){
        next = prev = null;
        e = data;
    }
    public AnyType getElement(){
        return this.e;
    }
    public Node<AnyType> next(){
        return next;
    }
    public Node<AnyType> prev(){
        return prev;
    }
    public Node<AnyType> setNext(Node<AnyType> x){
        return this.next = x;
    }
    public Node<AnyType> setPrev(Node<AnyType> x){
        return this.prev = x;
    }
}
```

And I have to implement several methods like this one:

```
 public AnyType findMax ( ){
    Node<AnyType> curr = first;
    Node<AnyType> max = first;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < size){
        if(cmp.compare(curr.e, max.e) > 0){
            max = curr;
            break;
        }
        curr = curr.next();
    }
    return max.e;
}
```

aparently the problem is with this statement: cmp.compare(curr.e, max.e)
but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong can someone please help me, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should remove the `break`, so it'll continue searching.

Comment: You are totally right, thanks but I still have the problem with the comparator

Comment: If you would like any input to your problem with your comparator, you’d better tell us what the problem is? That is, what’s it doing and in what way is it different from what it’s supposed to do? It also seems your findMax() doesn’t take into account the case where the queue is emapty?

Comment: You may also want to edit the question and add you comparator code.

Comment: that's the problem it is supposed to be a generic class that works with several types, my professor sent us a .class file to test it but after decompiling, it doesn't seem to have anything about comparator or the compare method